# change report controls .left property at runtime - print

Tags: ms-access, report

Windows 10 Access 365 32 bit

I have a report with 4 subreports. On one of the subreports I have an Image-control.

The Image-control needs to be placed on the report according to a calculated value.

This works fine when previewing the report. Troubles comes when trying to print it.

"*A custom macro in this report has failed to run, and is preventing the report from rendering.*"

This is the code I have placed in subreports Detail event, on Print event:

```
Me.imgMarker.Left = ((valGradient * 0.181) - ((Me.imgMarker.Width / conTwips) / 2)) * conTwips
Me.imgMarker.Top = 19.5 * conTwips
```

But a simple `Me.imgMarker.Visible = True` does the same thing.

All subreports are placed in the MainReports Detail section.

Comment: To preview printing, use **Print Preview**, not **Print View**. -- Try using the `Format` event instead.

Comment: The Format event: Still the same problem.

Comment: Hi Andre
Did you mean: Do not: acViewPreview, and then print from the menu? At least I tried doing an acViewNormal - and then there is no problem printing the report and positioning the image at the same time and that's OK for me.

Comment: Actually I meant "do not use **Report view** (`acViewReport`)", sorry for the confusion. It surprises me that `acViewPreview` + Print doesn't work, but `acViewNormal` does - but hey, if it works! :)

Comment: Well thanks any way, Andre. In any case, you got my thoughts on something else.